# Can baseUrl of docusign api change in future?

Tags: docusignapi

We create docusign account using REST API. In response we get basic account information like AccountId, Account GUId, BaseURL and etc. We save this base url & use same base url for other api transaction.

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountid}

Will this BaseURL remain same for this account/user or it can be change? I know we can use account/login method to identify BaseUrl, but we don't want to do this all time. Any idea base url will remain same or it can be vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the [baseUrl](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) once and use it for all subsequent Api calls. But it is at your own risk as the baseUrl might change if Docusign changes the internals of the API.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30904358/1219543) for more details